# IPC over shared memory segment - memcpy visibility

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory, volatile, memcpy

I have shared memory communication written in C.

The following structure stands in the very beginning of the allocated segment.

```
typedef struct {
    int closedCount;
    int shmId;
    int semId;
    int size;
    volatile bool closed;
    volatile unsigned int readCount;
    volatile unsigned int writeCount;
    volatile bool readBlocked;
    volatile bool writeBlocked;
} T_IpcData;
```

I use 2 semaphores - 1 for reader and 1 for writer.

Writer puts data to shared memory, updates writeCount and notifies reader semaphore. If writeCount - readCount == size, writer waits on writer semaphore.

Reader tries to read writeCount - readCount bytes from shared memory with memcpy, updates readCount and notifies writer semaphore. If readCount == writeCount, reader waits on reader semaphore.

Problem: Sometimes (very rarely) I have errors in my app which is caused by the data read is not the same as written.

I run tests on single CPU (8 cores) and Dual-CPU (16 cores) machines. OS - Ubuntu. Issue is rarely reproduced on both.

Question: what guarantees on "changes visibility" does memcpy provide? How can I make sure that reader properly sees all the modifications done in writer thread?

Thanks!

UPDATE (code)

```
template <class T>
    jlong Java_org_gridgain_grid_util_ipc_shmem_GridIpcSharedMemoryUtils_ReadShMem(
        JNIEnv *env, jclass, jlong shMemPtr, T dest, jlong dOffset, jlong len, jlong timeout) {
    T_IpcData *ipcData = (T_IpcData*) (((char *) shMemPtr) - BUF_OFFSET);

    int unreadCnt = GetUnreadCount(ipcData);

    while (unreadCnt == 0) {
        if (unreadCnt == 0 && ipcData->closed) {
            return -1;
        }

        // signal the other party, if it's blocked
        if (ipcData->writeBlocked) {
            if (__DEBUG) {
                cerr << "Before write semaphore notification 1 [semId=" << ipcData->semId << "]\n" << flush;
            }

            SemNotify(env, ipcData->semId, SEM_WRITE, ipcData);
        }

        if (__DEBUG) {
            cerr << "Before read semaphore wait [semId=" << ipcData->semId << "]\n" << flush;
        }

        ipcData->readBlocked = 1;
        SemWait(env, ipcData->semId, SEM_READ, timeout, ipcData);
        ipcData->readBlocked = 0;

        unreadCnt = GetUnreadCount(ipcData);
    }

    int bytesRead = 0;

    while (unreadCnt > 0 && bytesRead < len) {
        int pos = ipcData->readCount % ipcData->size;
        int len0 =  (ipcData->size - pos < unreadCnt)? ipcData->size - pos: unreadCnt;

        if (len0 > len - bytesRead) {
            len0 = len - bytesRead;
        }

        RW::FromShMem(env, dest, dOffset + bytesRead , len0, (void*) (shMemPtr + pos));
        ipcData->readCount += len0;
        bytesRead += len0;

        if (__DEBUG) {
            cerr << "Before write semaphore notification 2 [semId=" << ipcData->semId << "]\n" << flush;
        }

        SemNotify(env, ipcData->semId, SEM_WRITE, ipcData);
        unreadCnt = GetUnreadCount(ipcData);
    }

    return bytesRead;
}

template <class T>
jlong Java_org_gridgain_grid_util_ipc_shmem_GridIpcSharedMemoryUtils_WriteShMem(
    JNIEnv *env, jclass clsName, jlong shMemPtr, T src, jlong sOffset, jlong len, jlong timeout) {
    T_IpcData *ipcData = (T_IpcData*) (((char *) shMemPtr) - BUF_OFFSET);

    int bytesWritten = 0;

    while(bytesWritten < len) {
        // Wait for reader.
        int unreadCnt = GetUnreadCount(ipcData);
        int pos = ipcData->writeCount % ipcData->size;

        while (unreadCnt == ipcData->size) {
            if (ipcData->closed) {
                env->ThrowNew(env->FindClass(GRID_EXCEPTION), "Shared memory segment has been closed.");
                return -1;
            }

            // signal the other party, if it's blocked
            if (ipcData->readBlocked) {
                SemNotify(env, ipcData->semId, SEM_READ, ipcData);
            }

            ipcData->writeBlocked = 1;
            SemWait(env, ipcData->semId, SEM_WRITE, timeout, ipcData);
            ipcData->writeBlocked = 0;

            unreadCnt = GetUnreadCount(ipcData);
        }

        int len0 = ipcData->size - ((pos >  unreadCnt)?  pos :  unreadCnt);

        if (len0 > len - bytesWritten) {
            len0 = len - bytesWritten;
        }

        if (ipcData->closed) {
            env->ThrowNew(env->FindClass(GRID_EXCEPTION), "Shared memory segment has been closed");
            return -1;
        }

        RW::ToShMem(env, src, sOffset + bytesWritten, len0, (void*) (shMemPtr + pos));
        ipcData->writeCount += len0;
        bytesWritten += len0;
        SemNotify(env, ipcData->semId, SEM_READ, ipcData);
    }

    return GetUnreadCount(ipcData);
}
```

SemWait() calls semop() and SemNotify() calls semctl().

Comment: Please post the exact code that handles the semaphores, access to `readCount`, `writeCount`. There may be a race condition there.

Comment: Sergey, code uploaded. I have checked it for race conditions multiple times. Please, take a look, maybe I have missed something.

Comment: I recommend you retag this to c++ and have the c++ guys check it out.

Comment: Done, but there is nothing special from CPP. Only templates that have nothing to do with the problem I observe.